# LibGDX - change texture brightness

Tags: java, libgdx

There is a way to set the texture brightness with libGDX?
I prefer not to use GLSL for that, There is a way to do this with just libGDX?

I couldn't find something like that -

```
Texture tex = new Texture("tex.png");
tex.brightness = "0.5"; // Couldn't find something like that
```

If someone can help i will be glad.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like that.

But you can change the color of the SpriteBatch you use to draw it:

```
batch.setColor(0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F, 1F); //It will be darker
```

Comment: Thanks, its all i needed.. too bad it doesnt have something to change texture brightness.. it could be helpful for many people.